# How do I target the text value of my button using event?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I want to to target the text that is being used for my button. I tried to use event to target the text but that didn't work.

I have tried doing

```
changeColor = (event) => {
    let AllInterests = this.state.AllInterests;
    let i = 0;
    let SpecifcInterest = AllInterests[i]["interest"];
    let target = event.target.text;
    console.log(target);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.AllInterests.map((item) => (
          <View>
            <InterestButton
              text={item.interest}
              color={item.color}
              onPress={this.changeColor}
            />
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Interests;
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codsandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) for us.

Comment: can't you pass the text in this.changeColor like this.changeColor(item.interest) ?

Comment: @KhairulAnik how would i target it though?   When I do console.log(e.target.value) for that scenario I get an error that says value is undefined

Comment: @Samantha I guess you're using react-native. there you don't have access to the native DOM event because they are not regular DOM element. https://forums.expo.io/t/what-is-react-native-s-replacement-of-react-s-e-target-innertext/20908/2

Comment: @KhairulAnik I am using react native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest different approach by not accessing the DOM element if it's possible, instead you pass the text into the function.

```
changeColor = (buttonText) => {
  let AllInterests = this.state.AllInterests;
  let i = 0;
  let SpecifcInterest = AllInterests[i]["interest"];

  console.log(buttonText);
};

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.state.AllInterests.map((item) => (
        <View>
          <InterestButton
            text={item.interest}
            color={item.color}
            onPress={() => this.changeColor(item.interest)}
          />
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

export default Interests;
```

Answer (score 3):

First, assign a `value` property to your button and then use that `value` property from the event object in your function.

For example:

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
}

return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick} value="Hi">Hi</button>
    </div>
)
```

**OR**

If you don't want to give the value and directly use the text from the button you can use `innerText` property like

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.innerText);
}

return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={handleClick}>Hi</button>
    </div>
)
```

> **Both the snippets will output the "Hi" log on the console**

Comment: Updated the answer, can you please try that

Comment: Hey thanks for modifying it but I am still getting undefined.

Comment: Can you try using `innerText` property, updated the answer again

Comment: No its still undefined. I think it might because the text value is inside my button and I am using state to get the text....

Comment: Can you please share that part of your code? It will help to identify the issue.

Comment: @Samantha I think you could update your post by adding your state initial or constructors. Because that may be the problems from.